# Get rid of typeParam Exception when defining LoggerMessage

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I´m using serilog as a LoggingProvider in my ASP.NET Core WebApp and I want to use the LoggerMessage-features from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions. My logs are in JSON-format.

If I want to log an object with Serilog I have the possibility to either log a simple .ToString() of the object or to destructure the object with the @-Operator. Example:

ToString:

```
Log.Information("Some information about {MyObject}", myObject);
```

Destructured:

```
Log.Information("Some information about {@MyObject}", myObject);
```

Now I´m using `LoggerMessage` to define LoggingActions ones, and invoke them in an extension method of ILogger as described in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/loggermessage):

```
private static readonly Action<ILogger, MyObject, Exception> = // Exception is required
        LoggerMessage.Define<MyObject>(
            LogLevel.Information, 
            new EventId(1), 
            "Some Information about {MyObject}");
```

But I can´t pass an Exception as a message parameter to destructure the Exception. That means that I don´t have my exception available as a JSON-object in my logs but only something like this:

```
"Exception":"System.ArgumentException: Exception occured\r\nParameter name: test\r\n   at Test.Controllers.TestController.TestLog() in C:\\Source\\Repos\\Test\\Project\\Controllers\\TestController.cs:line 40"
```

One additional (little) disadvantage is, that I don´t want to have the same LoggingLevel for an errorMessage as for an informationMessage...

The only possibility I see right now, is to renounce the usage of LoggerMessages for my exception-message and to do it like this:

```
public static void LogMyObjectError(this ILogger logger, MyObject myObject, Exception ex)
{
    string msg = "Some error with {MyObject} {@Exception}";
    logger.LogWarning(msg, myObject, ex);
}
```

Any ideas how I can use LoggerMessage **and** "destructured Exception"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas how I can use LoggerMessage and "destructured Exception"?

You could achieve this by including exception object as another parameter for logging action:

```
private static readonly Action<ILogger, MyObject, Exception, Exception> _someErrorEvent =
    LoggerMessage.Define<MyObject, Exception>(
        LogLevel.Information,
        new EventId(1),
        "Some Information about {MyObject} {@Exception}");
```

However it becomes ugly when it's time to call logging action because you should duplicate exception object in passed parameters:

```
_someErrorEvent(logger, myObject, exception, exception);
```

You could fix that by defining your own helper (e.g. `LoggerMessageEx.DefineError<T1>()`) which is based on `LoggerMessage`:

```
public static class LoggerMessageEx
{
    public static Action<ILogger, T1, Exception> DefineError<T1>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, string formatString)
    {
        var action = LoggerMessage.Define<T1, Exception>(logLevel, eventId, formatString);
        return (logger, arg1, exception) => action(logger, arg1, exception, null);
    }
}
```

Now you could create logging action with following call:

```
private static readonly Action<ILogger, MyObject, Exception> _someErrorEvent =
    LoggerMessageEx.DefineError<MyObject>(
        LogLevel.Information,
        new EventId(1),
        "Some Information about {MyObject} {@Exception}");
```

And invoke it with passing just one exception object:

```
_someErrorEvent(logger, new MyObject(), exception);
```

For me, all this makes sense only if you have a lot of such events. Otherwise, I'd choose you approach with `LogMyObjectError()` method.

Comment: Great!! Was not able to see that :) Thanks a lot! Made just one little edit: I wouldn´t pass the exception twice because of redundant (unneccessary redundancy in my case) logInformation - but apart of that exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of destructuring the exception, which may have unintended consequences depending on the exception type, plugging in [*Serilog.Exceptions*](https://github.com/rehansaeed/serilog.exceptions) will achieve what you're after with the added benefit of being tailored to specific exception types.

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like I need to try this out.. Especially the DbEntityValidationException-case..

Comment: If I use the interfaces from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging - how can I benefit from Serilog.Exceptions? The Docs only show a call on Serilog.Logger.Error()-Method - am I blind to see the obvious or am I missing something?